# How to see data on a database in Visual studio 2008

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to see what data our database (SQL server Compact 3.5) in Visual Studio 2008?
I am unable to see it in SSME

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Server Explore` in `VS`

add a new connection to `sql server` -> right click on table -> click on write `query` -> write the query and click `Ctrl+R`
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it shows the database and tables but not the data they contain